# Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: hyperlink, router

I keep getting this error mess while doing this tutorial I think I'm putting the code in right?
I'm using **vs** as my editor.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Topbar = () => {
  return(
   <nav className='navbar navbar-light'>
     <div className='container'>
       <link to='/' className='navbar-brand'>
         Medium
        </link>
        <ul className='nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right'>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/' className='nav-link'>
              Home 
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/login' className='nav-link'>
              Sign in 
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/register' className='nav-link'>
              Sign up
            </NavLink></li> 
        </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
  )
}

export default Topbar;
```

i cant understand why i keep catching this error mess
Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `link`-tag instead of `Link`. Fix this and error should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Use capitalized Link instead of link

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href="/"><a>Medium</a></Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use Capitalized Link Tag **

HOME